# Settings and Switch Account in Windows 8 Tablet Apps

Tags: interaction-design, design, tablet, windows-8

I am designing a file browsing windows apps like one drive or dropbox. I tried Dropbox and Box on Windows 8 Surface. I didn't see how I can log out or switch account in this app. 
How those features are designed in Windows 8 and where are they?

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the Dropbox or Box apps in a while, but the pattern for Windows 8/8.1 apps is to access app settings through the charms bar. My guess is that this is the case for those apps.

Swipe from the right to pull out the charms bar, then tap on Settings. There should be an option for Account or something similar in the fly-out that appears.